# Backbone view in not rendering from collection.toJSON()

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am using backbone, handlebars, jquery for app. Following code line is not working

```
this.$el.find('.quiz-container').append(quiz.tmplt.result(this.collection.toJSON()));
```

Template is

```
<h2 class="score">Congratulation ABCD! You have scored {{score}} !!!</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Your Answer</th>
            <th>Correct Answer</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each qtext}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{this}}</td>
            <td>
                {{#each ../answer}}
                <span>{{this}}</span>
                {{/each}}
            </td>           
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my JSON file

```
[{
    "qid": "1001",
    "qtext": "This is question one?",
    "options": [{"id":"opt1", "str":"15%"},{"id":"opt2", "str": "16%"},{"id":"opt3", "str": "17%"},{"id":"opt4", "str": "19%"}],
    "answer": ["opt2"]},
    {
    "qid": "1002",
    "qtext": "This is question two?",
    "options": [{"id":"opt1", "str":"item0"},{"id":"opt2", "str": "item1"},{"id":"opt3", "str": "item2"},{"id":"opt4", "str": "item3"}],
    "answer": ["opt1"]},
    {
    "qid": "1003",
    "qtext": "This is question three?",
    "options": [{"id":"opt1", "str":"5%"},{"id":"opt2", "str": "2.5%"},{"id":"opt3", "str": "11%"},{"id":"opt4", "str": "0%"}],
    "answer": ["opt3"]}
]
```

I know, I can split this template and using collection.each method i can render each object from JSON file, but i want to keep it 1st template and render directly from collection data.

Thanks in advance

Vikram

Comment: Presumably `quiz.tmplt.result` is the compiled template function. Have you taken a quick look at what `this.collection.toJSON()` returns?

Comment: It returns all the models of that collection

Comment: But your template is looking for something like `{score: 6, text: [ ... ] }`, right?

Comment: No, my issue is the complete template should render once with score and `innerHTML` of `tbody` should be render for each question and its available options. I have achieved it by splitting it into 2 different templates, i.e., parent and child template and it works fine. but I wanted to keep one template only.

Comment: Then you need to pass `{ qtext: [ ... ], ... }` to the template function so that the `{{#each qtext}}` will have something to iterate over. You just have to rearrange your data to match your template or vice versa.